# Assign file content to a variable using C?

Tags: c

How can i read file and assign the file content into variable using C ?
for example: `program.txt` file is contain values like this

r1=2r2=4r3=5r4=6

i want to read the `program.txt` file and assign r1,r2,r3,r4 values to variable.
i tried with this example program, but it returns too many argument for `fgetchar()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n;
  char c;
  FILE *fptr;
   if ((fptr=fopen("E:\\program.txt","r"))==NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
   }

   fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n);
   fgetchar(fptr);
   printf("Value of n=%d",n);
   printf("Char is = %c", c);
   fclose(fptr);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Please share your code.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: i tried with `fgetchar()` but it returns too many argument error. Couldn't find good resource

Comment: C does not support accessing variables of the program by name during program execution. To perform storage and retrieval of values by name, you must write your own code (or get it from somewhere) to associate strings (representing names) with values. This requires some amount of knowledge about C, algorithms, and data structures, so it is not a topic for Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: then where would i ask this question ? @EricPostpischil

Comment: File format is unclear. What you want, exactly (and why) is unclear. How about, read char, check that it is 'r', then read digit for index, then read char and check that it is '=', then read digit for value. Then... try array r[] maybe?

Comment: i'll try thank you @hyde

Comment: @PathumLakshan: Properly, one would study textbboks on C, algorithms, abd data structures.

Comment: You probably should have asked *"How do I parse `name=value` pairs from a text file in C?"* instead, with a sample text file as an example. If your name parts can start with some other letter than `r`, then include those other examples. This is definitely solvable using a loop and `fscanf()`: each iteration of the loop will then yield both the name and the value of one pair.

Comment: You can use an array of `struct` with two members. One member holds a string identifier (or a pointer to it) and the other holds its value.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you ask `fscanf` to read an integer: `fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n);`
but your first character in the file is a letter. so fscanf can not find an int so it fails and stop there.

The solution is to write your assignation as one per line like that:

```
r1=1
r2=2
r3=3
```

then you ask fscanf to match the line and in place of the number you want to read to put the `%d` so it looks like that: `fscanf(ftpr, "r%d=%d\n", &n, &var);`

By the way: `fgetchar` does not exists, so there is no way your program actually compile, but you can use: `fgetc` that takes the FILE as argument and returns the next character in the file: `char c = fgetc(fptr);`

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic way to do this. YOu have to do the heavy lifting yourself

if you can reorg the file so its like Lavigne958 suggests

Then you need to do

```
int val[10];
while(!feof(fptr))
{
  fscanf(ftpr, "r%d=%d\n", &n, &var);
  val[n] = var;
}
```

if they must be called r1, r2, r3, ... then do

```
int *val[10];
val[1] = &r1; // yes I know I missed out [0]
val[2] = &r2;
...

while(!feof(fptr))
{
  fscanf(ftpr, "r%d=%d\n", &n, &var);
  *(val[n]) = var;
}
```